# How to set value in a variable of "use variables" using javascript in Klipfolio Dashboard?

Tags: javascript, klipfolio

I need to set data from HTML Component in a variable of Klipfolio using javascript as I am using a plugin for multiple selection from a dropdown box. I couldn't find any way to do that.

I tried with "set" method and other method, but it didn't work out for me.

Comment: What methods? Where did you try and "set". Provide code examples and/or what you would like to accomplish even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The dashboard has a function on it called "setDashboardProp". This function takes the following inputs:

1. scope: (Values: 1 = Klip Scope, 2 = Tab Scope, 3 = Dashboard Scope, 4 = User)
2. name
3. value
4. xid (klip or tab identifier)
5. secondaryId (tab identifier) (when scope == 1, tab)

So to set a tab scope variable named currentMax to 10 use the following call:

dashboard.setDashboardProp(2,"currentMax",10,dashboard.activeTab.id);

Check that value was set using getDashboardProp:

dashboard.getDashboardProp("currentMax",2,dashboard.activeTab.id);

I would suggest using the browser console in developer tools in either Chrome or Firefox to test out these calls before including in a Klip.